# Numerical ODE solution methods which are stable for the second-order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a question regarding the stabililty of the numerical methods for 2nd order ODE
$$
f^{''}(t) + 6f^{'}(t) + 45f(t) = 0
$$
if the discretization step is $\delta_t=\frac{1}{3}$, so which method is stable?
Explicit Euler? Implicit Euler, Heun method, 2nd order Milne method, or RK4?

Comment: Why don't you take the calculation tool of your choice and try this out? It should be instructive.

Comment: Note that the 2nd order Milne method is also known as the (weakly stable) central Euler or 2-tap Nystrom method.